# Ошибка ValueError при конвертации текстовых данных

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, машинное-обучение, scikit-learn

Есть текстовый файл. Конечной целью является построение прогноза по гребневой регрессии.

В конечной стадии сталкиваюсь с ошибкой формата данных:

```
 from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
          2 clf = Ridge(alpha=1.0)
    ----> 3 clf.fit(X, y_train)
          4 Ts=clf.predict(X_test_categ)
          5 print (ts)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'SalaryNormalized'
```

При попытке преобразования столбца в числовой формат, натыкаюсь на:

```
y_train = np.array(data_train['SalaryNormalized'])
y_train = y_train.astype(np.float)

----> 2 y_train = y_train.astype(np.float)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'SalaryNormalized'
```

Форматирование текстового массива во float. Как?

Comment: "конвертации формата данных переменной" - не совсем монимаю эту фразу, не могли бы вы пояснить, что она  значит?

Comment: @0xdb, исправил - надеюсь так немного понятнее...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В ваших данных в переменной `y_train` встречается текст `'SalaryNormalized'` вместо числа.

Как это "обойти":

```
data_train['SalaryNormalized'] = \
    pd.to_numeric(data_train['SalaryNormalized'], errors='coerce')
data_train = data_train.dropna(subset=['SalaryNormalized'])
y_train = data_train['SalaryNormalized']
```

Все значения которые не могут быть преобразованы в числа будут заменены `NaN`. 
В данном случае лучше удалить соответствующие строки.